# Plotly Dash - Conditional Numbers Formating in DataTable

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have very simple issue. I want to apply decimal places in specific rows in DataTable.
I use style style_data_conditional.

So one of conditions looks like below:

```
{
    'if': {
        'filter_query': '{Metric} = "Market Share Value Traded"'
    },
    'color': 'red',
    'type': 'numeric',
    'format': {
        'specifier': ',.2f',
    },
    'fontWeight': 'bold',
}
```

As an output rows with string= "Market Share Value Traded" are indeed red and bold, but I cannot force them to show only 2 decimals.

Documentation of plotly dash DataTable conditional formatting do not mention how to format decimals.